# Node.JS Sandbox include certain methods and libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods, sandbox

I am running Sandbox module in my Node.JS application which runs dynamic scripts from my database. By default Sandbox blocks access to Node methods and anything else in the Master process. I am trying to figure out how to include libraries and methods that I choose.

The process ONLY runs the code that is in the `sandbox.run()` and built as a string.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the Sandbox module, but you can use the VM module from node core. Start with [creating a context](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_createcontext_initsandbox) and then use [runInContext](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runincontext_code_context_filename).

Answer (score 1):

The module you're looking for is [vm2](https://github.com/patriksimek/vm2). `vm2` is a sandbox that can securly run untrusted code with whitelisted built-in node objects.